# Find distribution of following r.v.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There are $n$ different objects : $a_1 \dots a_n$. We may choose any objects and take it back. So everytime we have probability of choosing is $1/n$.

Let's suppose we $n$ times choose some element. Now let's $\mathbb{P}(\xi = k)$ is probability that we choose exactly $k$ different objects. We want to describe this probability and find $\mathbb{E} \xi$.

My attempt : first of all we need choose $k$ elements among all. First element we choose with unit probability, next one with $(n-1)/n$ \dots the $k$-th one with $(n-k+1)/n$. And other our choices should be among this $k$ elements. Hence we have : $\mathbb{P}(\xi = k) = \binom{n}{k} \frac{n!}{(n-k)! n^k} \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{n - k + 1}$.

Unfortunately I miss something because it even doesnt give me a distribution. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let us find the probability that exactly the objects $a_{1},\dots,a_{k}$
are picked.

Define: $$\hat{S}:=\left\{ i\in\left\{ 1,\dots,n\right\} \mid\text{object }a_{i}\text{ is chosen}\right\} $$

Then $\hat{S}$ is a random set and if we state that $S:=\left\{ 1,\dots,k\right\} $
then by symmetry: $$P\left\{ \xi=k\right\} =\binom{n}{k}P\left(\hat{S}=S\right)$$

Further with inclusion/exclusion we find that: $$P\left(\hat{S}=S\right)=P\left(\hat{S}\subseteq S\right)-P\left(\bigcup_{s\in S}\left\{ \hat{S}\subseteq S-\left\{ s\right\} \right\} \right)=$$$$\sum_{T\subseteq S}P\left(\hat{S}\subseteq T\right)\left(-1\right)^{\left|S\right|-\left|T\right|}=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{n}\left(-1\right)^{k-i}\tag1$$

So we end up with: $$P\left\{ \xi=k\right\} =\binom{n}{k}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{n}\left(-1\right)^{k-i}$$

---

**edit** concerning the expectation of $\xi$.

In order to find $\mathbb E\xi$ you better not use the distribution of $\xi$.

It can be solved by applying linearity of expectation and symmetry.

For $i=1,\dots,n$ define random variable $A_i$ that takes value $1$ if object $a_i$ is chosen and takes value $0$ otherwise.

Then: $$\xi=\sum_{i=1}^nA_i$$ and consequently:$$\mathbb E\xi=\mathbb E\sum_{i=1}^nA_i=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb EA_i=nP(A_1=1)=n\left(1-\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\right)$$

---

**edit** to enlighten the inclusion/exclusion part:

The inclusion/exclusion starts like this:

$$P\left(\bigcup_{s\in S}\left\{ \hat{S}\subseteq S-\left\{ s\right\} \right\} \right)=$$$$\sum_{s\in S}P\left(\left\{ \hat{S}\subseteq S-\left\{ s\right\} \right\} \right)-\sum_{s,t\in S,s\neq t}P\left(\left\{ \hat{S}\subseteq S-\left\{ s\right\} \right\} \cap\left\{ \hat{S}\subseteq S-\left\{ t\right\} \right\} \right)+\cdots$$

Note that we can write this also as:

$$P\left(\bigcup_{s\in S}\left\{ \hat{S}\subseteq S-\left\{ s\right\} \right\} \right)=$$$$\sum_{T\subseteq S,\left|T\right|=k-1}P\left( \hat{S}\subseteq T \right)-\sum_{T\subseteq S,\left|T\right|=k-2}P\left(\hat{S}\subseteq T\right)+\cdots$$

Comment: I don't understand the inc/exc. idea.

Comment: Do you agree with the first equality of $(1)$? The term $P\left(\bigcup_{s\in S}\left\{ \hat{S}\subseteq S-\left\{ s\right\} \right\} \right)$ can be worked out by means of inclusion/exclusion.

Comment: I agree with first equality that $P\left(\hat{S}\subseteq S\right)-P\left(\bigcup_{s\in S}\left\{ \hat{S}\subseteq S-\left\{ s\right\} \right\} \right)$

Comment: am I right that $T$ is some $i$ elements subset of $\{1 \dots k\}$

Comment: Yes, $T$ is some index standing for subsets of $S$. The last equality of $(1)$ is a workout on base of the cardinality of such sets. So there is an index $i$ taking values in $\{0,1,2,\dots,k\}$. This $i$ corresponds with $|T|$.

Comment: If we have something as $P(\bigcup_{s\in S}B_s)$ then with inclusion exclusion we get that this equals $\sum_{s\in S}P(B_s)-\sum_{s\neq t}P(B_s\cap B_t)+\cdots$. This leads (combined with the other term) to the second equality in $(1)$.

Comment: Observe that e.g. $\left\{ \hat{S}\subseteq S-\left\{ s\right\} \right\} \cap\left\{ \hat{S}\subseteq S-\left\{ t\right\} \right\} =\left\{ \hat{S}\subseteq S-\left\{ t,s\right\} \right\} =\left\{ \hat{S}\subseteq T\right\} $
where $T=S-\left\{ t,s\right\} $ is a subset of $S$ with cardinality
$k-2$ if $s\neq t$.

Comment: I have added something that might make  the PIE more clear.